# Security with $_GET Request

Tags: php, get

With the URL Structure like http://www.site.com/user/1, is it a security risk?

For example like here `http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1`

Isn't this a security breach. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Note that such a URL is not related to the `$_GET` superglobal. The latter one evaluates only GET parameters, i.e. `/somepage.php?var=value` would give you `$_GET['var'] == 'value'`. As with any user input, you need to validate it and make sure that it is correctly used; then there aren’t really any security problems.

Comment: It is a duplicate of thousands.

Comment: Please explain how the example url is a "security breach", or at least why you think it is.

Comment: Any edit should be done with a POST or PUT verb, but checking permissions is still needed, as is validating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please explain why you think it is a security breach.

If you mean that a user can simply change the number to access another user's edit page, yes they can. That can also be done with POST, the body can manually be altered (for example by creating a local html file that posts to your page, or by altering the body using a browser plugin).

You should however use a check on every page, to see whether the currently logged on user has the right to perform the action(s) that are performed on that page.

It can simply be done by:

```
$userIdToEdit = $_GET['ID'];

if ($userIdToEdit != $_SESSION['loggedOnUserId'])
{
    redirect("/NotAllowed"); // Deny access to the page
}

// if we end up here, the user may perform this action, like store POSTed data in db
```

However, while you have all flexibility you want, you might be repeating checks throughout pages. A solution to this would be using [RBAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control), where it would become like this:

```
checkRole(EditOwnProfile); // only logged on users may do this, redirects to /NotAllowed if necessary

// and check for another role 
$userIdToEdit = $_GET['ID'];
if ($userIdToEdit != $_SESSION['loggedOnUserId'])
{
    checkRole(EditOtherProfile); // admins may do this for example
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You should reject people access who don't need to access that page.

Answer (score 1):

It is only a security risk if you do not check permissions to edit (or whatever action) the target page.  For example in your sample URL, only userid 1 (or perhaps some sitewide admins) should be allowed to edit the page. Others would be redirected, or otherwise denied access.

Some consider incremental integer ids to be a slight security risk, as they can easily be guessed and scripted in a loop to probe for pages on which an attacker can take unauthorized action.  However, the practice of using incrementing integer ids is very widespread, and again depends upon proper access checking on each page load.

Finally, and perhaps most importantly, the first thing you need to do in the script handling that URL is validate the numeric id to be both numeric and identifying a valid resource.

Answer (score 0):

Using htaccess rewrite rules will not cause a security issue as long as your script is safe. you basically need to use sessions to keep track of who is allowed to access that page and with a good code you should be fine. and `user.php?id=1` and `/user/1` are both the same, they require the same amount of security

Answer (score 0):

In general, knowing the URI of a resource is not a security problem.

A security problem would be caused if an HTTP request could cause the data to be edited without an authentication/authorization step taking place.

Providing a form that invites a user to edit data without such a step, and then applying the security check only after the form is submitted would just be poor usability.

The particular example you give probably falls in to the poor usability category. I'm not going to attempt to submit an edit request to see if it falls into the security problem category, but I would assume it does not (given how long SO has been around and how popular it is).

Answer (score 0):

The edit action `http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1` is no security risk if you check the users permission properly.

On the other hand, an URL like `http://stackoverflow.com/users/delete/1` **is** a security risk as an attacker could fool an authorized user to open this URL, which would result in the deletion of the user with the id 1. This can be achieved by using an URL-Shortening-Service like bit.ly.

You can avoid this by using $_POST for actions like deletion and adding a token to the request to verify the source of the request.

Comment: Using POST instead of GET would stop sane bots from deleting content by accident. It provides no protection against malicious attacks.

Comment: He says " and adding a token to the request" so he's right. Keyword here also is [idempotence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), you should not alter the state of anything through GET.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Take care about how HTTP protocol works itself (how possibilities does have potential attacker).
In short - there is no difference in attacker's options if you decide to change that url into something like `/change-user` and hide the parameters like id in post params.

You need to secure authentication of that HTTP request (maybe by session created by standard login, you have more options how to do that).